# The meaning of "if any"

Tags: meaning-in-context, conditionals

I saw the following in a journal homepage.

> To defray the publication cost, authors are requested to arrange print charges of their accepted papers at the rate of US$ 40 per page from their institutions/research grants, if any.

I don't understand the meaning of **if any** in the above sentence. I have a paper with no grant. Should I pay anything?

Comment: ....if (there is/are) any.

Comment: ***Few if any***:  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/few%20if%20any

Comment: It _may_ mean you only have to pay if you have a research grant or can get funds from your institution, but I'm not sure.  However, there's academia.stackexchange.com, which has some posts on "page charges."  I suggest asking them--they may know about this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's been cross-posted to [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/88266/56207) and has gotten useful answers there.

Comment: It is certainly poorly worded.

Comment: When I was briefly dealing with the academic publishing biz about 40 years ago there were more clearly worded statements that said that, *if* you were associated with some business or institution that paid publishing costs for their employees'/members' submissions, then the expected/usual amount was $N per page.  If you had no such resource then the fee was waived.

Comment: @HotLicks, it has been a never-ending source of amusement that academic and trade journals hold contributing authors to a much higher linguistic standad than they hold themselves.

Answer (score 5):

The cited sentence

> To defray the publication cost, authors are requested to arrange print charges of their accepted papers at the rate of US$ 40 per page from their institutions/research grants, if any.

asks authors of accepted papers to arrange for their institutions (if they are affiliated with one) or their research grant (if they have received one) to pay the journal $40 per print page (meaning, presumably, per page of text appearing in the journal) to defray publication costs. So "if any" means, in the first instance, "if they are affiliated with any institution," and, in the second instance, "if they have received any research grant."

The quoted language does not address situations in which authors are neither affiliated with a particular institution nor the recipient of a research grant. My guess is that either the journal has a separate provision—detailed elsewhere—to cover institutionless, grantless authors or such authors get a free ride. It could also be that the journal almost never accepts papers from institutionless, grantless authors.

Comment: Thank you for decoding this mysterious sentence to explain its exact meaning. The 'if any' would have made far more sense -- possibly automatic sense to OP so as not to have needed to post this Q -- if the next sentence had explained what authors **without** an institution or grant should do! It is a reminder that any sentence we write whose meaning is very clear to us, might well turn out to be exceedingly perplexing to another reader. It is my language goal to be able to consistently write unambiguous sentences.